# Keword search on long text stored as image data type in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to do a keyword search on an image data type that stores long text. This is in SQL Server 2008.

I have been able to convert the image field into readable text in a view and via Power BI export however the SSMS query editor only displays a single character for the converted field and I am unable to do any type of character search on the returned value.

```
SELECT  
    WB.WORKORDER_BASE_ID AS BASE_ID, 
    WO.PART_ID, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), CONVERT(BINARY(8000), BITS)) AS LONG_TEXT1,
    CAST(CAST(BITS AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS LONG_TEXT2,
    CASE 
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), CONVERT(BINARY(8000), BITS)) LIKE '%ELLIP%' 
          THEN 'ELLIP' 
    END AS SEARCH_TEST_1,
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST(CAST(BITS AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%ELLIP%' 
          THEN 'ELLIP' 
    END AS SEARCH_TEST_2
FROM      
    dbo.WORKORDER_BINARY AS WB
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    WORK_ORDER AS WO ON WB.WORKORDER_TYPE = WO.TYPE 
                     AND WB.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = WO.BASE_ID 
                     AND WB.WORKORDER_LOT_ID = WO.LOT_ID 
                     AND WB.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = WO.SPLIT_ID 
                     AND WB.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = WO.SUB_ID
WHERE     
    WB.WORKORDER_TYPE = 'w' 
    AND WO.STATUS = 'r'
```

I can view the results of the datatype conversion, however not directly in the query editor, and I cant search the converted data type as needed.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: And another note: Image (and Text and NText) was deprecated since 2008 version first came out, and in any case Image is a binary type and not a textual. While upgrading, you should convert the long text stored in the Image data type to varchar(max) (or nvarchar(max) if it's unicode text).